# Header Name Not Found VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use Excel VBA macros to filter through a list using a search box.

Here is the code I have used:

```
Sub Button2_Click()
'PURPOSE: Filter Data on User-Determined Column & Text/Numerical value


Dim myButton As OptionButton
Dim SearchString As String
Dim ButtonName As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myField As Long
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim mySearch As Variant

'Load Sheet into A Variable
  Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Unfilter Data (if necessary)
  On Error Resume Next
    sht.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

'Filtered Data Range (include column heading cells)
  Set DataRange = sht.Range("D23:D27") 'Cell Range
  'Set DataRange = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range 'Table

'Retrieve User's Search Input
  'mySearch = sht.Shapes("Button2").TextFrame.Characters.Text 'Control Form
  mySearch = sht.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.Text 'ActiveX Control
  'mySearch = sht.Range("A1").Value 'Cell Input

'Determine if user is searching for number or text
  If IsNumeric(mySearch) = True Then
    SearchString = "=" & mySearch
  Else
    SearchString = "=*" & mySearch & "*"
  End If

'Loop Through Option Buttons
  For Each myButton In sht.OptionButtons
    If myButton.Value = 1 Then
      ButtonName = myButton.Text
      Exit For
    End If
  Next myButton

'Determine Filter Field
  On Error GoTo HeadingNotFound
    myField = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Button2, DataRange.Rows(1), 0)
  On Error GoTo 0

'Filter Data
  DataRange.AutoFilter _
    Field:=myField, _
    Criteria1:=SearchString, _
    Operator:=xlAnd

'Clear Search Field
  sht.Shapes("TextBox1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "" 'Control Form
  'sht.OLEObjects("UserSearch").Object.Text = "" 'ActiveX Control
  'sht.Range("A1").Value = "" 'Cell Input

Exit Sub

'ERROR HANDLERS
HeadingNotFound:
  MsgBox "The column heading [" & ButtonName & "] was not found in cells " & DataRange.Rows(1).Address & ". " & _
    vbNewLine & "Please check for possible typos.", vbCritical, "Header Name Not Found!"

End Sub
```

When I step through the code with F8 I get a error message saying the header name "Area" in cell D$23$ was not found when in fact I do have Area written in cell D23.

Comment: I do not see where you assign a value to `Button2`. Should it be `SearchString` or `ButtonName` instead in the Match?

Comment: How do you know that is the exact error occurring when using that error handling?

Comment: @dwirony the exact message is: "The column heading [Area] was not found in cells $D$23. Please check for possible typos."  It occurs when I get to the step `End Sub`

Comment: Because you made it that. It's just taking the last value of `MyButton` and the lastvalue of `DataRange.Rows(1).Address` and returning that message, when it looks like the error could be something else entirely.

Comment: Also, I get a different message when I press the button: "Can't execute code in break mode"

Comment: you have a typo in the match, you are referring to a variable that is not assigned a value.  Change your match to `myField = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ButtonName, DataRange.Rows(1), 0)`

Comment: @ScottCraner now I get Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: You use `ButtonName` and that equals the value in cell `D23`?

Comment: @ScottCraner your solution worked. I would accept an answer from you as my list filters now, but I am still getting an error after pressing the button: "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: This is just a guess, but change `sht.Shapes("TextBox1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = ""` to `sht.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.Text  = ""`

Comment: @ScottCraner now I get an error message that literally just says "400"

Comment: Make sure `"TextBox1"` is spelled correctly.

Comment: @ScottCraner please answer my question so I can accept your answer, your solution from earlier worked.